# Regex to replace single quote by ignoring "already replaced single quote" and "beginning/ ending single quote"

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string like this:

```
 var path = "'Ah'This is  a 'sample\'e'";
```

In the above string beginning and ending single quote(after double quotes) are as expected.
i.e `"'...............'";`
In the rest part of the string, there are single quotes (both replaced (i.e \' and un-replaced). I have a necessity to replace the single quote wherever it is not replaced. If it is already escaped, then no action needed.  I have a hard time to find suitable regex to replace this.
After replacing the string must look like this( Please note that beginning and ending single quotes must not be replaced.

```
"'Ah\'This is  a \'sample\'e'";
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: I suspect you have `var path = @"'Ah'This is  a 'sample\'e'";` as input. What is the expected output for `var path = @"'Ah'This is  a 'sample\\'e'";` and `var path = @"'Ah'This is  a 'sample\\\'e'";`?

Comment: Single quotes need no escaping. There are no escaped quotes in that string, just quotes.`\'` is simply replaced by `'`.

Comment: Please don't tell me you want to have this for SQL purposes. Do you?

Comment: Which means that no problem can be reproduced from this code the way it is. Perhaps the actual problem is something else? Why escape *single* quotes? Is this string going to be used to create a JSON string?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Having a problem X, thinking Y is the solution and asking about Y when that doesn't work. What is the actual question? It's not how to escape single quotes because they don't need escaping. It's not to ignore "already escaped single quote" because there's no such thing in C#

Comment: If the actual question is about SQL, the answer is *DON'T use string concatenation* to create SQL queries. Use parameterized queries. Not "eventually", not "but for now". It's actually a lot easier to write a parameterized query than try to get string concatenation to work. A microORM like [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) would make this almost trivial

Comment: If the question is about *JSON*, again, don't concatenate strings. Create an object graph, possibly using anonymous types, and let a library like JSON.NET serialize it to JSON.`JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new {a="aaa'sss'ffdd'',b=new {myarray=new[]{1,2,3}}})` will convert and escape all strings, objects and arrays to their correct JSON representation

Comment: My bad. It  was wrong usage to say escape. I edited the question. The need for replacing is to make a valid jpath ( i.e jsonpath). I have a valid json . I can't replace the single quote before passing on to jpath due to some reasons. So once the jpath is constructed I need to repalce.

Comment: You are already using some library, right? Does it have any escaping method built-in? Some serialization method?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : In my case the string can never have / or //  except when it is to escape a character.  So @"'Ah'This is a 'sample\\'e'" is not a valid  input. Jpath is a way to filter the json, and I'm not using any libraries for jpath.

Comment: Then you may use `Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!\\)(?!^)'(?!$)", @"\'")` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f!%5e%29%27%28%3f!%24%29&i=%27Ah%27This+is++a+%27sample%5c%27e%27&r=%5c%27))

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Wow.. Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I understand it is too much to demand.  Do you mind explaining this regex ? It would be a great help if you could . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(?<!\\)(?!^)'(?!$)", @"\'");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5C%5C%29%28%3F!%5E%29%27%28%3F!%24%29&i=%27Ah%27This%20is%20%20a%20%27sample%5C%27e%27&r=%5C%27). Regex graph:

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!\\)`  - a negative lookbehind that matches a location in string that is not immediately preceded with `\`
- `(?!^)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location in string that is not immediately followed with start of string (it is just failing the match  if the current position is the start of string)
- `'` - a `'` char
- `(?!$)` - a negative lookahead that matches a location in string that is not immediately followed with the end of string (it is failing the match if the current position is the end of string).

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew I found a small problem here...  Though @http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5c%5c%29%28%3f!%5e%29%27%28%3f!%24%29&i=%27Ah%27This+is++a+%27sample%5c%27e%27&r=%5c%27  shows that it works fine, it doesn't seem to be fine when the input is surrounded with double quotes in C# specifically

Comment: @SKN What do you mean? Please provide a sample string (as a string literal) and expected output. Best is to share a quick C# code fiddle so that  I could repro.

Comment: Actually it was my fault that I didn't state the problem clearly..   So the single quote need not come soon after the double quotes. https://dotnetfiddle.net/VfBVQQ  .If the input is  @"..Top..''!!!'..State", output must be  @"..Top..'\'!!!'..State"

Comment: Everything looks fine in the link you shared. But not in Visual Studio.. https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4659907/56420631-6044b500-62bc-11e9-9c76-9645af39a836.png

Comment: @SKN Why do you pay attention at the debug output? Is it your first experience with C# and VS? The `Console.WriteLine(output)` will show you the real output, not the debug view. The https://ideone.com/vmRoXe does what you need then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192097/discussion-between-skn-and-wiktor-stribizew).